# Is there a better way to store who likes, dislikes a profile in a relational database?

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I’m creating a small django application in which, a user can see the number of likes and dislikes on his or her profile as well as the people who have liked or disliked that profile.

My django model is:

```
class ProfileView(TimeStamp):
    PROFILE_RESPONSE = (
        (0, 'Like'),
        (1, 'dislike'),
    )

    user_from = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    user_to = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='views',
    )
    response = models.IntegerField(choices=PROFILE_RESPONSE)
```

In this table I’m storing who likes/dislikes the profile in `user_from` and to whom he likes/dislike in `user_to`.  In response `user_from` either likes or dislikes `user_to` (0 means Like  and 1 means dislike)

But this solution isn’t scalable and making queries like listing all the user(s) who have liked or disliked a particular profile will be quite inefficient.  So, is there any better option than this in a relational database.  n.b., I am using postgresql.

Comment: Do you know about aggregation? This might be of use here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/

Otherwise you could add four new (int) fields to the profile model that count own and profile's likes and dislikes.

Comment: Thanks for the aggregation link, but adding four fields won't be helpful because I also have to store user who have liked a particular like.

Comment: Could you write the actual code? I can't understand what you mean by "user_from | user_to | response(0,1)".

Comment: What I want to say is let say there is a user A,  and user B & C likes and D dislike A's profile. Now it is easy to store A's like and dislike count but I also want to store B,C and D's information that they have liked or disliked A's profile, so that user A can see who have liked his profile.

Answer (score 0):

Even for a fairly high number of users (millions), this model  is scalable so long as you aggregate results on a reasonably regular basis (like once a night).  You would essentially need to recalculate the following model on a regular basis:

```
from django.db import models

class UserLikeSummary(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserLike) # `ProfileView` didn't look like a model at first glance since it subclassed from `Timestamp`
    like_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislike_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

You could also just make a database view that kept tabs on the running aggregate total for you with a query like:

```
select user_to_id, count(id) 
  from appname_userlike 
  where response=0 
  group by user_to_id; 
-- this will keep tabs on likes, and you can have a similar query/view for dislikes
```

In django, this can be written as:

```
UserLike.objects.filter(
    response=0
).values('user_to_id').annotate(d_count=Count('id'))
```

An it will run reasonably fast so long as `user_to` is an indexed column.